# CDI with desktop application

Tags: java, cdi, desktop-application

Have some business logic using CDI (@javax.inject.Inject and @javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit). Want reuse it inside desctop application.

Added beans.xml into META-INF folder. Set Java 7 as default. Wrote simple class:

```
public class Main {

       @Inject
       private static AggregatedUserQueries aggregatedUserQueries;

       public static void main(String[] args) {
             System.out.println(aggregatedUserQueries);
       }
}
```

Of course it prints "null" to console. Are there any way to use CDI with desctop application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned `@Boris Pavlović`, you can bootstrap Weld and get beans programmatically. However, it is possible to get injection working too. You need to define startup method in your desktop application which will "replace" your `public static void main(String ... args)`. Consider:

```
public class Main {

    @Inject
    private Bean bean;

    public void startup(@Observes ContainerInitialized event) {
        this.bean.sayHello();
    }
}
```

This `startup()` method will be invoked when Weld is bootstraped. You can achieve it by executing `org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain` as a main class.

Answer (score 1):

Add weld to your project

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

then somewhere in your application initialize it:

```
WeldContainer weld = new Weld().initialize();
```

and lookup a bean:

```
AggregatedUserQueries queries = 
  weld.instance().select(AggregatedUserQueries.class).get();
```